# What approaches are there in Java EE for asynchronous communication?

Tags: java

I want to know what approaches there are in Java EE that I can use them for asynchronous communication especially in distributed systems? (in fact what approaches there are in java that designed for this aim)

Answer (score 2):

Some options:

**Asynchronous web services**

Pros:

- Well known standard
- Easy to debug
- Can participate in a JTA transaction

Cons:

- No guarantees on delivery
- No persistance, retry, etc.
- Not so good performance (HTTP, serialization overhead)

**Java Message Service**

Pros:

- Well known standard
- Can participate in a JTA transaction
- Can be setup so it guarantees delivery, retries if needed
- Multiple implementations to choose from
- Good performance

Cons:

- Requires a separate server (if not built in into your appserver)
- Requires experience with JMS

See this for implementations: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service#Provider_implementations

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JMS` for async message passing